# Why after executing db.dropDatabase() in MongoDb , db command switches to dropped database?

Tags: mongodb

Mongo shell output image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbLUT.png

Comment: Hi Anand Kumar - can I suggest a way of improving your question? Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your data format, copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It doesn't switch to the dropped database** because it never really drops the database. When you enter `db.dropDatabase()`, what MongoDB does is clear all the files associated with that DB -- clear all the collections, their indices and more. What it doesn't do is remove the `db` completely and switch to another one.

It has been designed in a way that all the contents will be dropped but not the database itself. You get the same database, but a new document `insertion` in it will allocate a fresh set of data files.